# How would I build a drupal view that shows information from a case including who holds each of the case roles?

Tags: civicase, drupal-views

I would like to build a drupal view that shows information from a case including who holds each of the case roles. For example the view would show

Case Id: 1234 
Case Status: Scheluled
Role 1 contact: Bob
Role 2 contact: Mary
Role 3 contact: School
Case Client: James

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: These case roles are relationships in CiviCRM, so your view is about identifying the contacts who have the relationships with your case client. I'd probably start by setting up my view to be a CiviCRM Cases type view. Then I could identify the case ID and client for each case, and then use one or more views relationships to let me access the related contact names. Doing this in my head though, so no guarantee that it is the right way.